# Problems with videobg.js and video anchor point

Tags: javascript, video

I have a site at the following location:

http://www.summerserver.com/video

I am utilizing the following codebase for the video:

http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/

The issue I am having is as follows:

The video displays in the div, however due to user resolution/screen differences, it looks different on each screen.  I want it to be 100% width.  That part works.  The issue is that th anchor point for the video stretching seems to be the upper left corner.  I would like it to the lower left corner.  The higher the resolution of the user screen, the more that the bottom of the video is being cropped off.  I would rather the top of the video be cropped and not the bottom.

The following is the .js I am using:

```
//videoDemo 
$('#div_demo').videoBG({
    mp4:'_assets/vid/index_video.mp4',
    ogv:'_assets/vid/index_video.ogv',
    webm:'_assets/vid/index_video.webm',
    poster:'_assets/img/index_video.jpg',
    scale:true,
    zIndex:0
});
```

I have no idea how to tell it to use a different point of anchor (or if this is even possible).  The best part of the video content is toward the bottom, as the top is more just sky stuff....  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to add the property width: "100%" to the videoGB call.

```
//videoDemo 
$('#div_demo').videoBG({
    mp4:'_assets/vid/index_video.mp4',
    ogv:'_assets/vid/index_video.ogv',
    webm:'_assets/vid/index_video.webm',
    poster:'_assets/img/index_video.jpg',
    scale:true,
    zIndex:0,
    width: "100%"
});
```

for the bottom issue, you have to enter in the videogb.js and modify it.

at the line 148 (in my js version) or search "// video element" comment. You will find the css definitions for the video object. Change the "top" attribute for "bottom".

this could be like this:

```
// video element
var $video = $('<video/>');
$video.css('position','absolute')
    .css('z-index',options.zIndex)
    .attr('poster',options.poster)
    .css('bottom',0) // top property changed
    .css('left',0)
    .css('min-width','100%')
    .css('min-height','100%');
```

Just keep in mind that all the videos that you will use with this version will be aligned at bottom.